# Fail to create ODBC Systems Datasource for OBIEE 12.2.1.4 Admin tool

Tags: oracle, obiee

On the client machine where Admin tool is installed, navigate to "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools".
Click on `Data Sources (ODBC)` to open it.
Navigate to the System DSN page, and click on "Add" button.
Select the Oracle BI Server-[ORACLE_HOME] as the driver name.

However, getting the following error:

> The setup routines for the Oracle BI Server ODBC driver could not be loaded due to system error code 1114: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (OBIEE server <ORACLE HOME>\oracle_common..\bi\bifoundation\server\bin\nqssetup.dll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be solved by removing the Oracle_Home from the windows environments variable.